# Select min() retornando valor diferente de 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer um `select` onde pega-se o menor valor encontrado, que não seja 0 (zero),

```
SELECT MIN(VALORTARIFA) MENORTARIFA FROM TABELA
```

No comando acima, caso exista algum valor 0,00, ele me retornará 0,00 e eu desejo somente o maior valor acima de 0,00, (0,01) já me interessa.

Tem como eu obter isso ?

Comment: Tentou com um `WHERE` ?

Comment: Você ta fazendo isso nos dois bancos? é MySql ou Sql-Server?

Comment: Não .. só no SQL Server

Comment: SELECT MIN(VALORTARIFA) MENORTARIFA FROM TABELA where valortarifa > 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso a solução é usa o `Where`.

```
SELECT MIN(VALORTARIFA) MENORTARIFA 
FROM TABELA 
WHERE VALORTARIFA > 0
```